# Hibernate duplicates object after merge

Tags: java, swing, hibernate

I have two objects who are in bi-directional relationship.

```
public class Entity1 extends AbstractEntity implements Serializable{
...
//bi-directional many-to-one association to Entity2
@OneToMany(mappedBy="entity1", fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
private Set<Entity2> entityTwos = new HashSet<Entity2>();
}


public class Entity1 extends AbstractEntity implements Serializable{
...
//bi-directional many-to-one association to Entity1
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="N_ENTITY1")
private Entity1 entity1;
}
```

So when I modify Entity1 and do this:

```
Entity2 entity2 = new Entity2();
            entity2.setValue("I");
            entity2.setDate(new Date());

entity1.addEntityTwo(entity2);

Entity2HibernateDao dao = new  Entity2HibernateDao();
dao.save(entity2);

getEnitity1Dao().merge(nalog);
```

everything is ok in database, but after i restart the application, there are two rows in my JTable for Entity1. If I delete:

```
Entity2HibernateDao dao = new  Entity2HibernateDao();
dao.save(entity2);
```

Entity1 other attributes of Entity1 are refreshed in database, but of course there are no records for Entity2.
I also tried with update() instead of merge(), but it didn't work also.
Am I connecting references of Entity1 and Entity2 correctly? Or is it something else? 
Thanks.

Comment: You need to also call `entity2.setEntity1(entity1);` in order to save them properly.

Comment: Actually,I generated this code, in method addEntityTwo(), there is already line: entity2.setEntity1(this), so I think that is not the problem, since it adds correctly in database, but I think objects are duplicated in session. Thanks, anyway.

Comment: How are you trying to load them? If you are using a list something like `session.list()` wrap them into a `set`.

Comment: Lets see the dao objects.

Comment: If you are using `Criteria` you need to add the `distinct` clause. Something like `criteria.setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);`

Comment: The problem was in my dao method findAllByValue1()... I changed it a bit, and now it works... but still I don't understand why. Here's code: http://pastebin.com/d2GdnUK0

Comment: When you use findByCriteria(), by default it will create number of parents equal to the number of database rows. Lets say if you have one parent and two children, when you query on database with left join, you will be able to see two rows as output. Hibernate just put them into the pojo's. As I said you need to add the `distinct` clause.

Comment: @Rp- thanks, I tried that and it also works. I totally forgot that hibernate would use join, I guess it happens when working late. Thanks one more time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `Criteria` like `findByCriteria()` by default it will create number of parents equal to the number of database rows. Lets say if you have one parent and two children, when you query on database with left join, you will be able to see two rows as output. Hibernate just put them into the pojo.

Either you need to wrap your results into a `set` or

```
criteria.setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);
```

will give you the desired results.